# Error in creating HTTP Recive Adapter for Biztalk 2010 in IIS 7.0 (Windows 7)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

[image: Picture of the problem]

I am creating an HTTP Receive Adapter for Biztalk 2010 in IIS 7.0.
Below are the steps used ;

1. In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager window, in the
   center pane, in the IIS section, double-click the Handler Mappings
   icon.
2. In the right pane, click Add Script Map. In the Add Script Map
       dialog box, in the Request path box, enter BTSHTTPReceive.dll.
3. Click
       the ellipsis (…) next to the Executable box, then browse to
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server
       2010\HttpReceive\BTSHTTPReceive.dll, and then click Open.
4. In the
       Name box type BizTalk HTTP Receive Adapter, and click OK. In the
   new
       Add Script Map dialog box that appears, click Yes.

After these steps I get the following error :

`The specified module required by this handler is  not in the modules list. If you are adding a script Map handler the IsapiModule or the CgiModule must be in the modules list.`

Comment: Any luck resolving your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I noticed you missing was the following steps:

> 8.In the Request Restrictions dialog box, click the Verbs tab and then
>   select One of the following verbs. Enter POST as the verb.
>
> 9.On the Access tab, select Script, and then click OK.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559072(v=bts.70).aspx

Also, make sure that IsapiModule is registered and enabled on the Modules page.  If it's missing, you may not have configured IIS to use ISAPI.  You might want to check your IIS configuration in Server Manager.